# Search result to show link to the page not to the pdf file

Tags: 7, search

I am using the [Search file attachments](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_file_attachments) module (which searches for text from pdf files after they are indexed), and everything works fine.

But I would like in Search result to **display link** to the content (where I uploaded the file) not **link to the PDF** itself, so that the user goes to that page and from there he can choose to see the PDF.

I am still new to Drupal, but from what I have read that I have to alter `$search_results` in `search-results.tpl.php` and use `template_preprocess_search_results()` to display what I want (*not sure if this is the right way*) or is there another way to this?

**EDIT:**

I found that I could edit `search_file_attacments.module` and there is the link attribute in `$results[]` I just have to figure out how to get nid (so I can get the url) from fid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I can't install the [Search File Attachments](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_file_attachments) module at this moment, but you can read at the module's page:

> The module is based on the core search and no other module is
>   required.

And I don't see any template page inside the module.

As in the `search-result.tpl.php` you will only have access to the `$snippet` variable, this is not a solution for you, because `$snippet` is a string, see the code inside `search-result.tpl.php`:

```
<?php if ($snippet): ?>
  <p class="search-snippet"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>><?php print $snippet; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So your best bet should be implement the `template_preprocess_search_results()` in the template.php file of your theme.

See this example:

```
function THEME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
    dpm($variables); //you need devel module to use dpm
}
```

Inside `$variables['result']` you will have the values that you need to make your modification. See the `dpm()` output:

[image]

If you want modify the `$snippet` variable then change the value inside the function like this:

```
function THEME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  //searching the info that you need
  $variables['snippet'] = 'The new value';
}
```

Comment: about the `search-result.tpl.php` that is from core and i tought that i could overwrite this but as you said i have to this on the module itself so my bad . I will try this now and thanks for the explainations really helpful.